# DBATools offline install - export-dbainstance was not found

Tags: sql-server, powershell, dbatools

I followed the instruction at https://dbatools.io/offline/:

1. download zip & unzip
2. run `$env:PSModulePath` to find all the paths.
3. copy to `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`.
4. run `Get-ChildItem -Recurse   "C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules" | Unblock-File`

When I try to run `Export-DbaInstance -SqlInstance` I got below error :

> The term Export-DBAInstance is not recognized".

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: When you unzipped the dbatools files, did you also follow the instructions to _Once you’ve extracted the folder, make sure you rename it from dbatools-master or dbatools-development to plain o’ dbatools._?  Until I did that on my test machine, I also could not find Export-DbaInstance.

Answer (score 5):

You need to import the module using `import-module dbatools`

See [Properly importing the module](https://dbatools.io/install/)

> Specifying the path to the .psd1 file

hope that helps you !

Also, what Scott commented is documented in the same link you have ([just read the page carefully](https://dbatools.io/offline/) to see if you are not missing any steps):

> Once you’ve extracted the folder, make sure you rename it from dbatools-master or dbatools-development to plain o’ dbatools.

Comment: Folder was renamed to dbatools.

Comment: import-module dbatools failed with this error:  Import-Module : The 'C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules\dbatools\dbatools.psd1' module cannot be import
ed because its manifest contains one or more members that are not valid. The valid manifest members are ('ModuleToProce
ss', 'NestedModules', 'GUID', 'Author', 'CompanyName', 'Copyright', 'ModuleVersion', 'Description', 'PowerShellVersion'
, 'PowerShellHostName', 'PowerShellHostVersion', 'CLRVersion', 'DotNetFrameworkVersion', 'ProcessorArchitecture', 'Requ

Comment: What version of powershell you are using ?

Comment: I found a server with powershell 4.0.  I did all the steps above (including import-module dbatools).  Now I can run "Export-DBALogin" but I still can't run "Export-DBAInstance".  I still got the "EXport-dbainstance is not recognized" message.  Very weird, appreciate your help.